# what are distribution by fitdistrplus R package

Tags: r, distributions, goodness-of-fit

How can I find all distribution that fitdistrplus package support. I find some examples from what I discovered what is required *distr* name, few example: if I am looking for log normal distribuiton distr name is "lnorm", if I am trying to fit Chi-Square Distribution then name for distr is "chi-squared", and so on. Is there some where in package manual where I can find all suported distributions.
I am interested in distributions that support positive integer values with big variance and relatively small mean (right skewed). Cullen and Frey graph suggested log normal distribution, data AIC and BIC for log normal model are the lowest but KS.test don t support this model.So I am trying to fit to other model but how to find right name for "dist".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The fitdistrplus FAQ](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/fitdistrplus/vignettes/FAQ.html#how-do-i-know-the-root-name-of-a-distribution) claims to fit distributions for which `d`, `p`, `q` and `r` functions are available, whether in base R or a package or which you have written yourself (though in more obscure ones you will need to provide sensible `start` values).

Common distribution names such as `chisq` can be found in the [R-intro manual](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.html#Probability-distributions)